# java.lang.StackOverflowError while creating a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I encountered rendering problems java.lang.StackOverflowError. I copied the stack to clipboard along with the main xml code. Part of the contents  of the clipboard is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at android.view.RenderNode.<init>(RenderNode.java:174)
    at android.view.RenderNode.create(RenderNode.java:196)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3591)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3682)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor303.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:93)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:138)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
```

The main_activity.xml code :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/layout1">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.paramjeet.memegenerator.TopSection"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment" />
```

TopSection.java

```
package com.example.paramjeet.memegenerator;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TopSection extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false);
return view;
    }
}
```

Fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/toptext"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_res"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Pls help.

Comment: What layout does your fragment use?

Comment: I used Relative Layout

Comment: Can you show how you inflate it (your `TopSection.onCreateView()` method)?

Comment: is that a runtime exception or it is some issue when you show the xml's preview on AndroidStudio ?

Comment: It's not a runtime exception. I get this error when I try to add the fragment from the custom folder. You can find it in the design section of xml.

Answer (score 5):

You can see in the stack trace, that the LayoutInflater is called recursively. So it seems like there is an error in the layout of the fragment where it includes recursively its own layout.

I would be able to tell you more if you post the layout of the fragment too.

Comment: That's exactly what I ment :)